# Convert date to dd/MM/yyyy in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to get my calendar to print what day it is in dd/MM/yyyy format, but it just doesn't seem to work.

My code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date now = new Date("19/11/16");
form.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(form.format(now));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(now);
System.out.println(cal.get((Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));

if(cal.get((Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) < 7 || cal.get((Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) > 1) {
     System.out.println("It's a weekday"); 
}
else {
     System.out.println("It's a weekend");
}
```

And the output is:

> 10/07/17
>
> 3
>
> It's a weekday

Can anyone spot the issue?

Comment: simply, change your date pattern from `dd/MM/yy` to `dd/MM/yyyy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` constructor you are calling is creating a `Date` with the wrong fields, to initialize your `Date` with your format parse the `String`. Like

```
Date now = form.parse("19/11/16");
```

Making sure to either catch (or rethrow) `ParseException`. With those two changes I then get

```
19/11/16
7
It's a weekday
```